# Embed SSL certificates

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, ssl-certificate, embed

I am coding a program(server-client) in python 2.7, that exchange data through sockets. I use SSL to secure the connection. But here is the thing. I want to make the client and the server executables with pyinstaller, and i want the SSL certificate and the key to be "hidden" somewhere inside the python code... so i can have only ONE file, and not several. I tried to load the certificate through a variable that contained the certificate, but appareantly the certificate needs to be loaded through a file. What options do i have ?

Answer (score 0):

Appereantly there isn't any answer to this question... so i figured out something else. I saved the certificate in a variable in my pythonic code :P and then before connecting to the server, the client saves the certificate to a temp file, and at the end delete it.